# How to find monitor count in mac os by Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to find count of monitor in mac OS by Cocoa.I can not use carbon.This code written in carbon but i want to do it in Cocoa framework.

```
CGDisplayCount dspCount;
CGError err ;
err = CGGetActiveDisplayList(0, NULL, &dspCount);
return (int)dspCount;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `NSScreen` class:

```
return [[NSScreen screens] count];
```

See the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScreen_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSScreen/screens).